# Shut down issues in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: shutdown, reboot

My Ubuntu 16.04 does not shut down. When I click on **shut down** option, it shuts down but it start by itself again even when there is no command for booting. I also want to know whether I can install HP Probook 4540s drivers on it or not.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the shutdown issue? It will shutdown automatically? Can you see it finishing the shutdown process? Or it's just powered off?

Comment: Do you mean it does 'reboot' if you choose 'shutdown'?

Comment: Try this command int the terminal and see what happens: 
shutdown -h now

Comment: Do you have laptop-mode-tools installed? If not, check after installing it.

Comment: Also, since you're on 16.04, the new command for shutdown is 'sudo systemctl poweroff', as everything is being managed by systemd.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite often a power management setting within your bios. Specifically, check your configurations on network devices (wifi & e-net).

Disable wake from sleep settings or power-management on wifi. If that solves it you can then iteratively try different settings until you have the desired result.